# Consequences of exchangeability of random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Consider two random variables $X_i$ and $U_i$ respectively distributed as $F_{X_i}(\cdot)$ and $F_{U_i}(\cdot)$ for $i=1,...,N$. Let $X:=(X_1,...,X_N)$ and $U:=(U_1,...,U_N)$ be respectively distributed as $F_X(\cdot)$ and $F_U(\cdot)$. Let $F_{X,U}(\cdot)$ be the joint distribution of $X,U$.

Assume that $F_{X,U}(\cdot)$ is exchangeable with respect to the indices $i=1,...,N$.

Could you help me to show that

1) $F_{U}(\cdot)$ and $F_{X}(\cdot)$ are exchangeable with respect to the indices $i=1,...,N$

2) $F_{U_i}(\cdot)$ is equivalent to $F_{U_j}(\cdot)$ $\forall i \neq j$